# Eclipse OpenCV Undefined reference and Binary not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

This is the code that I am trying out for a basic OpenCV program. I am using OpenCV 2.4.6.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat im = imread(argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "lenna.png", 1);
  if (im.empty())
  {
    cout << "Cannot open image!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  imshow("image", im);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Also I am using MinGW and am including the required libraries using [this](http://share-thevision.blogspot.in/2013/02/opencveclipse-on-windows.html) guide. On building all the OpenCV functions are declared as undefined references and the compilation generates the error message saying **Launch failed. Binary not launched.**

I checked the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860657/undefined-reference-to-eclipse-c) but on applying the changes I still cannot get it to work. Where am I going wrong?

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6 and a 64-bit windows 7.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It sounds like the compiler/linker can't find OpenCV.
Where is it installed ? Are you sure the headers and dynamic libraries are available to Eclipse ?
Are you sure you are linking against it ?

Comment: How do I check? I have just unzipped in C. And on including the header file like you have instructed it says no such file or directory and unresolved inclusion.

Comment: nothing is wrong with `#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"`