# Compiled C binary in Eclipse SIGSEV's

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I've been trying to get a working program running via Eclipse (for easier debugging) but I can't seem to get it done.

I have a simple command that compiles the program via the terminal:

```
gcc -m32 *.c -lm
```

I can then execute `./a.out` properly.

To make use of the user-friendly `gdb` plugins in Eclipse I'd like to compile and run it in Eclipse as well.

So far I have added `-lm -m32 -w` to the "Miscellaneous" field in the project settings under "Cross GCC Compiler" as well as in the "Miscellaneous" field under the "Cross GCC Linker".

The program seems to compile fine (see below). However, when I select the `libslip` binary file and try to execute it it crashes promptly.

When I run the `libslip` executable via terminal I get the following output:

```
Debug$ ./libslip 
Killed
```

When I run it via Eclipse I get this:

```
<terminated> libslip [C/C++ Application] <path>
```

The `gdb libslip` output is the following:

```
Reading symbols from libslip...done.
(gdb) b 1
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb4d3: file ../SlipTest.c, line 1.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/christophe/School/Semester 2/Programming Language Engineering/Section 5/eclipse-workspace/slip/Debug/libslip 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

The console output for compilation process in Eclipse:

```
19:10:24 **** Build of configuration Debug for project slip ****
make all 
Building file: ../SlipDictionary.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipDictionary.d" -MT"SlipDictionary.d" -o "SlipDictionary.o" "../SlipDictionary.c"
Finished building: ../SlipDictionary.c

Building file: ../SlipEvaluate.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipEvaluate.d" -MT"SlipEvaluate.d" -o "SlipEvaluate.o" "../SlipEvaluate.c"
Finished building: ../SlipEvaluate.c

Building file: ../SlipGrammar.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipGrammar.d" -MT"SlipGrammar.d" -o "SlipGrammar.o" "../SlipGrammar.c"
Finished building: ../SlipGrammar.c

Building file: ../SlipMain.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipMain.d" -MT"SlipMain.d" -o "SlipMain.o" "../SlipMain.c"
Finished building: ../SlipMain.c

Building file: ../SlipMemory.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipMemory.d" -MT"SlipMemory.d" -o "SlipMemory.o" "../SlipMemory.c"
Finished building: ../SlipMemory.c

Building file: ../SlipNative.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipNative.d" -MT"SlipNative.d" -o "SlipNative.o" "../SlipNative.c"
Finished building: ../SlipNative.c

Building file: ../SlipPool.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipPool.d" -MT"SlipPool.d" -o "SlipPool.o" "../SlipPool.c"
Finished building: ../SlipPool.c

Building file: ../SlipPrint.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipPrint.d" -MT"SlipPrint.d" -o "SlipPrint.o" "../SlipPrint.c"
Finished building: ../SlipPrint.c

Building file: ../SlipRead.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipRead.d" -MT"SlipRead.d" -o "SlipRead.o" "../SlipRead.c"
Finished building: ../SlipRead.c

Building file: ../SlipScan.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipScan.d" -MT"SlipScan.d" -o "SlipScan.o" "../SlipScan.c"
Finished building: ../SlipScan.c

Building file: ../SlipTest.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -m32 -w -MMD -MP -MF"SlipTest.d" -MT"SlipTest.d" -o "SlipTest.o" "../SlipTest.c"
Finished building: ../SlipTest.c

Building target: libslip
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc -m32 -lm -w -shared -o "libslip"  ./SlipDictionary.o ./SlipEvaluate.o ./SlipGrammar.o ./SlipMain.o ./SlipMemory.o ./SlipNative.o ./SlipPool.o ./SlipPrint.o ./SlipRead.o ./SlipScan.o ./SlipTest.o   
Finished building target: libslip


19:10:24 Build Finished (took 560ms)
```

**CodeBlocks build log**

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in Slip1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "Slip1 - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in Slip1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipDictionary.c -o obj/Debug/SlipDictionary.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipEvaluate.c -o obj/Debug/SlipEvaluate.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipGrammar.c -o obj/Debug/SlipGrammar.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipMain.c -o obj/Debug/SlipMain.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipMemory.c -o obj/Debug/SlipMemory.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipNative.c -o obj/Debug/SlipNative.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipPool.c -o obj/Debug/SlipPool.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipPrint.c -o obj/Debug/SlipPrint.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipRead.c -o obj/Debug/SlipRead.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipScan.c -o obj/Debug/SlipScan.o
gcc -Wall -g -w  -c /home/christophe/Desktop/CodeBlocks/Slip1/Slip1/SlipTest.c -o obj/Debug/SlipTest.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/Slip1 obj/Debug/SlipDictionary.o obj/Debug/SlipEvaluate.o obj/Debug/SlipGrammar.o obj/Debug/SlipMain.o obj/Debug/SlipMemory.o obj/Debug/SlipNative.o obj/Debug/SlipPool.o obj/Debug/SlipPrint.o obj/Debug/SlipRead.o obj/Debug/SlipScan.o obj/Debug/SlipTest.o   
Output file is bin/Debug/Slip1 with size 136,52 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: You might have to use gdb to run the Eclipse compiled output to see what/where the error is

Comment: I did that, and it gives not much extra information to be honest. Answer updated.

Comment: For the time being I'm using CodeBlocks. This works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have **finally** found it! The answer is to not manually add `-lm` but to add it to the libraries.

The way to make it work was:

Right Click Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C Linker > Libraries > add "m".

This made it compile and run perfectly! :)

I found it thanks to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860702/1225786